# Various job statistics using yarn and hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop

I've recently installed a 2-node hadoop 2.2.0 using the new yarn framework.

The jobs run and everything **looks** dine, but I wanted to know if there is a way to actually verify both nodes are running the job and not just one (I can't seem to find any relevant information about this matter in the `hadoop jar ...` commands' output, where the mapreduce completion statistic is displayed.

I've also wanted to know how can I verify both nodes are storing information for the DFS. I ran `df` and it seems only ONE node is actually storing information (I've `hadoop dfs -put` big text files).

So, in short:

1. How can I tell which nodes actually ran a specific job?
2. How can I tell which datanodes actually hold what information (I use replication = 2 to make sure both nodes share the load of information I've put on the DFS, after reading some tutorials).

It's really hard for me to Google this specifically because Hadoop isn't as covered as other topics I'm used to Google and most threads I end up running into are unanswered or irrelevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to check the Job Tracker Web UI (port 50030) - from here you can list the number of active Task Trackers as well as the number of map tasks they have both run (and completed, failed + errored).
2. You can use a command line tool to list the blocks and their locations:

   `hadoop fsck <path> -files -blocks -locations`

   See this link for more info on the fsck cmd: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#fsck

Comment: follow up:

I now can see that only the slave is running the map-reduce and the master doesn't.

The master I'm using is way stronger and I want it to perform mapreduce operations as well.

Do you know what are common reasons for this? or maybe can draw an overview of the decision of "who does what"?

Comment: Do you have 'nodemanager' running on the master node? Run 'jps' and confirm.